# Find formula for decomposition $\mathbb{C}[x]$ using basis $\{f = (x-c)^k\}$ $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers

How to find formula for decomposition $\mathbb{C}[x]$ using basis $\{f = (x-c)^k\}$ $k \in \mathbb{N}$
I only proved that $\{f = (x-c)^k\}$ $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is basis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**  Use the Taylor series.....